# Jquery - Calling a ajax function within ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can I use ajax function withing a ajax function.

In my case there are two ajax calls. First ajax will return some data , If it is successful then the second ajax should be called .

Below is my code snippet,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    url: "my service url here"
    dataType = "json",

    //success - 1
    success: function(data) {

        //I ll collect the data from service 
        //now the second ajax must run.
        //Because in first call I ll receive some data 
        //That data I going to use in my second call   
        $.ajax({
                alert('inside ajax-2');
                type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                    url: "my second service URL here",
                    dataType: "json",

                    //success - 2
                    success: function(data) {

                        //some functionality 

                    } //success-2
            } //success-1
        }); //ajax - 2
}); //ajax - 1
```

Some more info :
I had checked chrome dev console and the error I am getting is

```
//success - 1
success: function(data) {
   //Error message : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

That was the error message I got.

And yes I cleared the syntactical mistakes and I was getting the same error message.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
async: false,
url: "my service url here",
dataType : "json"

//success - 1
success: function(data) {

    //I ll collect the data from service 
    //now the second ajax must run.
    //Because in first call I ll receive some data 
    //That data I going to use in my second call   
    $.ajax({
            alert('inside ajax-2');
            type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                url: "my second service URL here",
                dataType: "json",

                //success - 2
                success: function(data) {

                    //some functionality 

                } //success-2
        } //success-1
    }); //ajax - 2
}); //ajax - 1
```

I checked the service URL in RESTClient extension of firefox browser and again yes , there is Jsondata coming from that service.

Any good suggestion will be highly appreciable

Merry Christmas :)

Comment: It should be working, but I've not yet tested it. What error you get in Chrome Dev Console ?

Comment: Yes , I had checked chrome dev console and the error I am getting is

    //success - 1
    success: function(data) {
       //Error message : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

That was the error message I was getting

Comment: You first ajax request is a POST. Should it be expecting some data ? That one seems to me a server-side error.

Comment: What was your problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your scripts.

In the first ajax call, where are the commas to separate the members ?

```
url:"my service url here",
dataType= "json",
```

and this should be:

```
dataType : "json",
```

Going back to your answer, yes you can but, what if you had the third ajax call?
Your code would be a mess and really hard to read.

The best would be to use [promises](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

This is the best way to work with asynchronous in javascript (that's also the reason why I've commented your `async:false` ).

You can read how promises work [here](http://www.vasanthk.com/jquery-promises-and-deferred-objects/).

`$.ajax` already returns a promise:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url:"my service url here",
       dataType: "json",
    });
```

which could be chained with another one:

```
promise.then(function(result){ });
```

I tend to prefer the approach where I split my ajax call in different function which create a new promise and return it; just in case I want to manipulate the result:

You can split the two ajax calls:

```
function FirstAjaxCall()
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       // async : false,
       url:"my service url here",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (jsonData) {
           deferred.resolve(jsonData);
       },
       error: function (req, status, error) {
           var errorMessage = (error.message) ? error.message : error;
           deferred.reject(errorMessage);
       }
    });

    return deferred.promise();

}
```

and

```
function SecondAjaxCall()
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       // async:false,
       url: "my second service URL here",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (jsonData) {
            deferred.resolve(jsonData);
       },
       error: function (req, status, error) {
            var errorMessage = (error.message) ? error.message : error;
            deferred.reject(errorMessage);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();

}
```

Now you could resolve the first one and chain the second one:

```
FirstAjaxCall()
    .then(function(result){
        return SecondAjaxCall(result);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        // final result
    })
    .fail(function(reason){
        // reason should contain the error.
    });
```

As you can see `FirstAjaxCall()` is resolve in the `.then()` branch and it passes it's result in the anonymous function. Same thing happens with the second ajax call `SecondAjaxCall()`. If something fails in the first or the second call the errors are trapped here:

```
.fail(function(reason){
     // reason should contain the error.
 });
```

The beauty of promises is you can chain them or execute them in [parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023696/219406).

Comment: I Think that by default, $.ajax return a promise. So there are no need to create a deferred promise just return $.ajax(.......)

Comment: Yes, I know. I tend to prefer this so I can, maybe, process the result before returning it.

Comment: Probably I should mention it in my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Something wrong in your code that I can see is that `}//success-1` is before `});//ajax - 2` and it should be after.

also there is a missing coma ( `,`) after `url:"my service url here"`,

replace the '=' you have by ':' for your two dataTypes.

your should correct that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below in a structured way:

```
//First method with callback
function myFirstCall(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async:false,
    url:"my service url here",
    dataType= "json",
    success:function(data){
       callback();
    });
}

// Second method
function mySecondCall() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async:false,
    url:"my second service url here",
    dataType= "json",
    success:function(data){
    });
}

//Let's trigger it
myFirstCall(function() {
  mySecondCall();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change "=" after the first "dataType" to ":"

```
    dataType= "json", =>  dataType : "json",
```

and move "alert" function to the outside the second $ajax block.

```
  $.ajax({                      => alert('inside ajax-2');
        alert('inside ajax-2');    $.ajax({
```

Last, order of closing brackets are opposite.

```
         }//success-1   =>  });//ajax - 2
          });//ajax - 2    }//success-1
```

The following code should work as you thought.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async:false,
    url:"my service url here"
    dataType : "json",    
    //success - 1
    success:function(data){

      //I ll collect the data from service 
      //now the second ajax must run.
      //Because in first call I ll receive some data 
      //That data I going to use in my second call

      alert('inside ajax-2'); 
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async:false,
            url: "my second service URL here",
            dataType: "json",

             //success - 2
             success: function (data) {

                 //some functionality 

             }//success-2
         });//ajax - 2
     }//success-1
 });//ajax - 1
```